# How to transfer local sql server or database to another computer 

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a project with 4 other guys, and we are developing an android app with a DB. Now, we are going to use a localhost for our SQL Server, I want to be able to take the database from my laptop and copy it to the other guys' computers. I"m using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

Any ideas of how to do it? I don't mind to copy the entire localhost server if we can do that.

BTW, I tried to backup the DB on my laptop by right-click on the DB (created `.bak` file) but there is no restore option on the other computer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup your data base and restore in the other machines

**edit**

If you dont find the restrore option, please try using sql script

ex:

```
RESTORE DATABASE nwind_new FROM DISK = 'c:\backups\northwind\nwind.bak'
WITH
MOVE 'northwind' TO 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\Data\nwind_new.mdf'
MOVE 'northwind_log' TO 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\Data\nwind_new_log.ldf'
```

You can try

Answer (score 0):

See these links about backup and restore:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966495.aspx

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sreekarm/archive/2009/09/11/move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another-server-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

---

To restore your database see this useful link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

its weird you dont see the restore option. You could try deattaching the DB from its location, copy the files (DB and LOG) to the new location and attach it there.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)